# $\mu \ll m$ finite Borel implies $x \mapsto \mu(A + x)$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Why is it true that if $\mu$ is a finite Borel measure on $\mathbf{R}$ which is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure $m$, then $x \mapsto \mu(A + x)$ is continuous for any fixed Borel set $A$?

I want to use the $\epsilon-\delta$ characterization of absolute continuity, since $\mu$ is finite.  This amounts to showing that $m(A_x \Delta A_y) \ll 1$ when $|x-y| \ll 1$, where $A_x = A + x$ and $\Delta$ is the symmetric difference.

Why is this true?

I didn't find this post helpful: 
[$\mu$ is a finite Borel measure on $\Bbb R$, absolutely continuous w.r.t. to the Lebesgue measure $m$. Prove that $x \mapsto \mu(A+x)$ is continuous.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1416665/mu-is-a-finite-borel-measure-on-bbb-r-absolutely-continuous-w-r-t-to-the)

Thanks.

Comment: I believe I have the answer.  (1)  Show for $U = \bigcup_j (a_j, b_j)$ disjoint that $m(U \Delta U_x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$.  This is not hard.  It implies by above that $\mu(U_x \Delta U_y) \ll 1$.  (2)  For general $A$, approximate above by $U$ in $m$ hence in $\mu$ by above.  Then estimate $\mu(A_x \Delta A_y) \leq \mu(A_x \Delta U_x) + \mu(U_x \Delta U_y) + \mu(U_y \Delta A_y)$; the triangle inequality is valid because $\mu$ is finite (c.f. Folland chapter 1 exercises).