# $\mu(A+x)$ is continuous implies $\mu \ll m$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $\mu$ is a finite Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}$ and $m$ is lebesgue measure. Then, if $\mu(A+x)$ is continuous in $x$, then $\mu \ll m$.

My approach was simply use the definition of continuity, Let $A\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ with $m(A) = 0$, then
$$ m(A+(y-y_0))\le m(A) + |y-y_0| = |y-y_0|<\delta\Rightarrow |\mu(A+y)-\mu(A+y_0)|<\epsilon $$

I think I am totally doing wrong. I hope that anyone could give me direction. Thanks.

> I could not understand [A note on translation continuity of probability measures by S. Zabell.](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2244564?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) and looked at [$μ≪m$ finite Borel implies $x↦μ(A+x)$ is continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1628286/mu-ll-m-finite-borel-implies-x-mapsto-mua-x-is-continuous?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: For all $A$?  You didn't say so.

Comment: @GEdgar sorry yes for all $A$ in Borel set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is Zabell's argument (on $\Bbb R$): If $\mu$ fails to be absolutely continuous with respect to $m$, then there is a Borel set $B$ with $\mu(B)>0$ but $m(B)=0$. By translation invariance of Lebesgue measure, you then have $m(B+t)=0$ for every $t\in\Bbb R$. (Here $B+t:=\{x+t:x\in B\}$ is the translate of $B$ by $t$.) By Fubini,
$$
\int_{\Bbb R} \mu(B+s)\,ds = \int_{\Bbb R} m(B-x)\,\mu(dx)=0.
$$
It follows that $\mu(B+s)=0$ for Lebesgue-a.e. $s\in\Bbb R$. By the assumed continuity of $s\mapsto\mu(B+s)$, you even have $\mu(B+s)=0$ for *all* $s$. In particular, take $s=0$ to see that $\mu(B)=0$, a contradiction.